# Multiple intermediate CA servers sharing index.txt cert file

Tags: ssl, openssl, certificate, ca, certificate-revocation

I have multiple intermediate CA servers creating certs. I can see these new certs been added to index.txt.
My question is on cert revocation. 
If Server 1 creates a cert then server 1 goes down. 
Then I go to server 2 to revoke this cert how does server 2 know about this certificate? 
Is it possible to share index.txt information across multiple CA servers. 
Reason using multiple servers is for high availability

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: There's nothing wrong with wanting high-availability, but generally issuing certificates is something that doesn't happen very fast, and where having the overhead to synchronise between multiple servers shouldn't be a problem.